# where do attributes go for function declaration

Tags: c++, attributes

I'm a bit confused about the location of **[[]]** attributes in a function **declaration**.

This site (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function) says to put attributes at the end..

Quote:

> noptr-declarator ( parameter-list ) cv(optional) ref(optional)
>   except(optional) attr(optional)

But for a function **definition**, place attributes at the front..

Quote:

> attr(optional) decl-specifier-seq(optional) declarator
>   virt-specifier-seq(optional) function-body

If I disregard the advise for declarations, and place attributes at the front (as per definition) then the compiler hints make more sense (it warns that my function **is** returning).

This is what I tried:

> //warning: ‘noreturn’ function does return [enabled by default]
>
> [[noreturn]] void no_return() ;
>
> //[[noreturn]]
>
> void no_return() {  } ;

I'd appreciate any help to understand this better, thanks.

Comment: That's not the end of a declaration, that's the end of a declarator. Cppreference updated with the mini-example from [dcl.dcl]p2